# How do I run a website on a smartphone app?

Tags: cordova, web, local, smartphone

Recently I started making an app in Cordova.

However, yesterday I found out that PHP and SSI only run on the server of a website instead of the local machine. This means that I cannot run php code locally on my smartphone either.
So all login systems, navigation, includes, etc are now unusable in my app.

I would like to know how I can run a smartphone app (simple index.html file) that redirects to a website without using a browser.

Answer (score 2):

Your server would expose services that can be called from your Cordova app via XHR. So for example, your PHP code would have a service your mobile app can call, passing in a username and password, and it would return JSON that signifies if the result was good or bad. Essentially your PHP code is just a remote API provider.

Comment: The login may not be that hard but the first thing where I had problems with is including files. I always used PHP to include html/php files into another one so I could use my header, background, etc easily without having to include it on every single page. That is the main reason why I wanted PHP... the main reason why I want the app to be runned on a web server

Comment: You should consider a MVC framework then for your client side code. While it won't necessarily give you simple PHP includes, it will allow for better code reuse on your client side.

Comment: but is there no simple piece of code that enables me to run a website inside my app? Something similar to a browser? I will be using enough web services to force the user to have a network connection but I also want to be able to have an app running over my website.

Comment: No, there is no simple piece of code that will do this for you. Unless you just want to use a browser.

Comment: If you just want to show a webpage, use a web browser, they usually perform better than webviews. But @RaymondCamden is wrong, there is an easy way of loadin an external url on a phonegap app, open the config.xml and change the  <content src="index.html" /> to  <content src="http://www.yourwebsite.com/index.html" />, or you can do a javascript redirect from your local index.html using window.location.href='http://www.yourwebsite.com/index.html'. I don't recommend developing apps like this, but it's possible.

Comment: ok, I was wrong, but I'm not sure I'd ever recommend doing that with a real app. And heck, would Apple even allow that?

Comment: I don't recommend it either. I've read some people saying they do something like that and the app was approved. Not sure if they allow it or didn't notice while reviewing.